# How can I add blur with 2pt of radius in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

I want to create something like that:

[image]

I've tried this one:

```
var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

but this creates very dark blur. But I need exactly dark blur(black color) with 2pt of radius.

Can I achieve that in Swift?

Comment: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light?

Comment: @Joakim but this is white blur. I need black one

Comment: show exactly what you need.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I've added screenshot. In case of .Dark blur, I got this one: http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52428a0ae4b0c4a5c2a2cede/t/545f6291e4b01d7732a08b7d/1415537298011/?format=1500w , but I want much lighter black, with 2pt of radius

Answer (score 6):

You can't control the radius of the blur of a `UIVisualEffectView`. You can achieve what you want by snapshotting the view you want to blur and applying a CoreImage's "CIGaussianBlur" filter to that snapshot then displaying the blurred image in a `UIImageView` placed directly above the view you want to blur. With `CIGaussianBlur` you can apply a blur radius to an arbitrary length.

You can use an extension on `UIView` to make this more convenient:

```
extension UIView
{
    func snapshotView(scale scale: CGFloat = 0.0, isOpaque: Bool = true) -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, opaque, scale)
        self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func blur(blurRadius blurRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage?
    {
        guard let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else { return nil }

        let image = self.snapshotView(scale: 1.0, isOpaque: true)
        blur.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blur.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

        let ciContext  = CIContext(options: nil)

        let result = blur.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!

        let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0,
                                  width: frame.width,
                                  height: frame.height)

        let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(result, fromRect: boundingRect)

        return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Then you can add a semi transparent overlay to determine how dark the blur is, for example:

```
let overlay = UIView()
overlay.frame = view.bounds
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.30)
viewIWantToBlur.addSubview(overlay)
let image = viewIWantToBlur.blur(blurRadius: 2.0)
imageView.image = image
```

For more information on this method and a more robust working example you can see [here.](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable) You should be aware that this is performance intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way out if you are using a **storyboard**.
First you need to add a "**Visual Effect View with Blur**" from storyboard right above where your image,UIUiew or uielement is to be seen.
Now draw the **outlet of the Visual effect view** as follows:-

```
 @IBOutlet weak var blurredViewVisulaEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
```

and add these two lines in the viewDidLoad method

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
blurredViewVisulaEffect.effect = blurEffect
```

**MANIPULATION of the view to make it according to our requirement:-** 
Now if you want to customise the blurriness of the image, then change the value of alpha of **UIVisualEffectView** from storyboard.Keep the value of **Alpha** within 0.5 to 0.8 to obtain desired blurriness.
And if you want to change the shade/color of the view, as mentioned by you between light and dark then you need to set the background color of your UIVisualEffectView to black and change its **opacity** from 100% to 30%(or may be 40 as required).

Then set the border of the view to 2 px as follows in your viewDidLoad()

```
blurredImageViewVisulaEffect.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
blurredImageViewVisulaEffect.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Comment: Apple very explicitly advises against changing the alpha of a `UIVisualEffectView`.

Comment: @chicobermuda - Apple gives that advice because a lesser alpha *"... causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all."* Note that they do not say that *all* effects have a problem with such alphas - perhaps this is not a problem with UIBlurEffect?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change blur radius using ios private API. I have a solution for you:
https://github.com/perfectdim/CustomBlurEffectView

Usage:

```
import CustomBlurEffectView

let customBlurEffectView = CustomBlurEffectView(
    radius: 20, // Set blur radius value. Defaults to `10` (CGFloat)
    color: .cyan, // Set tint color value. Defaults to `nil` (UIColor?)
    colorAlpha: 0.4 // Set tint color alpha value. Defaults to `0.8` (CGFloat)
)
customBlurEffectView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
addSubview(customBlurEffectView)
```