# Create a custom blur view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiblureffect

I need to add a blur view to my app.

I've tried `UIBlurEffect` but there are just 3 option (Light, Dark, ExtraLight), and I need something between Light and Dark.

I understood the only option I have is to create a custom blur view, but how can I do that?

Any idea?

Comment: modify the alpha value of a uiview. Or get the blur image and use it!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri what blue image?

Comment: blur image. Design a blur image in photoshop and use it!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri it's not possible to export a blurry image, according to what I know

Comment: You can export any kind of image from photoshop!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri not a blur, because it needs to be changed according to the image under it. Am I wrong? Can you please try and write here how you did that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add blur with 2pt of radius in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935214/how-can-i-add-blur-with-2pt-of-radius-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way out if you are using a **storyboard**.
First you need to add a "**Visual Effect View with Blur**" from storyboard right above where your image,UIUiew or uielement is to be seen.
Now draw the **outlet of the Visual effect view** as follows:-

```
 @IBOutlet weak var blurredViewVisulaEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
```

and add these two lines in the viewDidLoad method

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
blurredViewVisulaEffect.effect = blurEffect
```

**MANIPULATION of the view to make it according to our requirement:-** 
Now if you want to customise the blurriness of the image, then change the value of alpha of UIVisualEffectView from storyboard.Keep the value of **Alpha** within 0.5 to 0.8 to obtain desired blurriness.
And if you want to change the shade/color of the view, as mentioned by you between light and dark then you need to set the background color of your UIVisualEffectView to black and change its **opacity** from 100% to 30%(or may be 40 as required).